# Prove that image of a continuously differential path is a null set

Tags: calculus, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

I got by the following exercise: prove that the image of a continuously differential path $\gamma:[0,1] \rightarrow R^2$ is a null set.

I know that I need to find some cover of intervals $I_j=[a_j,b_j]$ of the image that satisfy  $$\sum_{j=1}^\infty |I_j| < \epsilon$$ for any $\epsilon>0$.

However, I am not really sure how to do it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$ uses disks or rectangles, not intervals. The idea of the proof is that since paths are one dimensional, we can cover these paths with rectangles of negligible width and hence negligible area.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I need to use the fact that $\gamma$ is continuously differential.  So I can bound the differential by some positive constant $M$. But how do I proceed from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\gamma: [0,1]\to\Bbb{R}^n$ for $n\geq 2$ be continuously differentiable. Since it is continuously differentiable, it is Lipschitz continuous with Lipschitz constant $C$, i.e. there exists a $C\geq 0$ such that for all $t_1,t_2\in[0,1]$, $$\| x_2-x_1\| \leq C|t_2-t_1|$$ where $x_i = \gamma(t_i)$. This implies that $$\gamma([t_1,t_2])\subset 
B(x_1,C|t_2-t_1|),$$ a closed ball centered at $x_1$ with radius $C|t_2-t_1|$.

Take $k+1$ equally spaced points along $[0,1]$ with $$0=t_0 < t_1 < \dots < t_{k-1} < t_k = 1$$ Then, for each $i$, $$\gamma([t_i,t_{i+1}])\subset B(x_i,C|t_{i+1}-t_i|) = B\left(x_i,\frac{C}{k}\right) := B_i$$ so that the curve $\gamma([0,1]) \subset \bigcup\limits_{i}B_i$.

The volume of a ball with radius $r$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is proportional to $r^n$, so the volume of each $B_i$ is proportional to $\frac{1}{k^n}$. Then, the sum of the volumes is an upper bound for the volume of the union, and it is proportional to $$k\cdot \frac{1}{k^n} = \frac{1}{k^{n-1}}$$ Then, as $k\to\infty$, the upper bound for the volume goes to $0$ as long as $n\geq 2$.

Thus, we can create closed ball cover of the curve with arbitrarily small volume, so the curve must be a null set.

Comment: Thanks! this is a really nice proof

Answer (score 1):

**Sketch:**

Denote by
$$ L = \int_0^1 \Vert \gamma'(t) \Vert dt $$
the length of our curve. Let $1>\varepsilon>0$ and pick $\delta>0$ such that 
$$ \vert x - y \vert < \delta \Rightarrow \Vert \gamma(x) - \gamma(y) \Vert< \varepsilon $$
this we can do as continuous functions on compact sets are uniformly continuous. Now set $y_j=\gamma(\frac{j}{n})$ and denote by $[y_j, y_{j+1}]$ the segment between $y_j$ and $y_{j+1}$, i.e.
$$ [y_j, y_{j+1}] := \{ t\cdot y_{j} + (1-t) y_{j+1} \ : \ t\in [0,1]  \}$$
Set
$$ p_n := \bigcup_{j=0}^{n-1} [y_j, y_{j+1}].$$
This is a piecewise linear interpolation of our curve. Now we thicken this interpolation up, in such a way that it contains the original curve. For this pick $n>\frac{1}{\delta}$, then by uniform continuity every point on the image of the curve has distant at most $\varepsilon$. Therefore, we have 
$$A_n :=\{ x\in \mathbb{R}^2 \ : \ dist(x, p_n)\leq \varepsilon \}\supseteq Im(\gamma)$$
Now we are left to show that the measure of $A_n$ is small. Indeed, I leave it to you to show that we have
$$ \vert A_n \vert \leq \varepsilon \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \Vert y_{j+1} - y_j \Vert + \varepsilon^2 \cdot \pi \leq  (L+\pi ) \varepsilon$$
The idea behind the first inequality is that you thicken up in the orthogonal direction, thus you get the length of the segment times the maximal distance ($=\varepsilon$) plus you get halves of balls at the beginning and the end of the linear interpolation. For the second inequality we used that $\varepsilon<1$ (and thus $\varepsilon^2 <\varepsilon$) and the inequality
$$ L \geq \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \Vert y_{j+1}-y_j \Vert. $$

Answer (score 0):

Think of applying fubini theorem to the characteristic function over the path !

Comment: Well, I haven't studied this theorem yet. I'm looking for another direction